# Do, while Loop for Craps Game program isn't terminating properly

Tags: java, loops, logic, do-while

I've read several submitted questions with a "Craps Game" title, comparing it to what I've written and can't seem to find the logic error in my loop. Everything about the program runs fine. But when I enter point state the loop doesn't terminate when values 7 or the point number is reached. I wrote my own die and pairOfDie classes for this. Here is the code:

```
        //if/else statement for entering point state on initial roll
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You rolled an " + die1.getValue());
            System.out.println("You've entered Point State!");

            //tally money total and save point number
            moneyTotal = start + point;
            pointNumber = die1.getValue();

            //print information for user
            System.out.println("Money Total is: " + moneyTotal);
            System.out.println("You need to roll another " + pointNumber
                    + " to Win $25 ");
            System.out.println("Roll anything BUT a 7 or your Point "
                            + "you win $10 and roll again.");

            /*"point state" loop that should continue to roll die unless 
            the player'spoint number or a 7 is rolled. 
            This should also keep tally of money won during each roll*/

            do
              {
               //point state roll
               die1.Value();
               System.out.println("You rolled a " + die1.getValue());
               System.out.println("You win $10 and " +
                            "get to roll again! ");
               moneyTotal += point;
               System.out.println("Money Total is: " + moneyTotal);

               }while(die1.getValue() != pointNumber || die1.getValue() != 7);

                //statement to handle if the roll comes up as point number
                //after entering point state
                if(die1.getValue()== pointNumber)
                {
                    System.out.println("You rolled your point number! "
                            + "you win $25 but the game is over. ");
                    moneyTotal += point;
                    System.out.println("Money Total is: " + moneyTotal);
                }

                //statement to handle if roll is a 7 after entering
                //point state
                else if(die1.getValue() == 7)
                {
                  System.out.println("You rolled a 7 " 
                          + "you lose $25 and the game is over");
                  moneyTotal -= lose;
                  System.out.println("Money Total is: " + moneyTotal);
                }
        }
```

EDIT:  Output is
You rolled an 4 You've entered Point State! Money Total is: 110
You need to roll another 4 to Win $25
Roll anything BUT a 7 or your Point you win $10 and roll again.
You rolled a 10 You win $10 and get to roll again!  Money Total is: 120
You rolled a 8 You win $10 and get to roll again!  Money Total is: 130
You rolled a 4 You win $10 and get to roll again!  Money Total is: 140
You rolled your point number! you win $25 but the game is over. Money Total is: 150
You rolled a 7 You win $10 and get to roll again!

Answer (score 0):

You need "&&", not "||", in your condition.  The die is bound to be either not equal to point OR not equal to 7.  You want to continue while it is not equal to point AND not equal to  7.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be an AND statement not an OR in your while condition.

```
while(die1.getValue() != pointNumber && die1.getValue() != 7);
```

Comment: wow. I'm dumb. I think I'm just way too close to this. I've been staring at it for 3 hours. Thank you. Sorry for the idiotic question.

Comment: No need to feel bad, we all have our moments :D !